# Rails view activerecord sql statements on debug console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-debug

I am using [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) gem in my Rails 3.2 application.

How do I view the resulting SQL statement of active record method calls on the debug console?

For eg: If I run `Product.all` on the debug console it prints out all the products. I would also like to see the `"Select * from Products"` as well. Is this possible?

Edit
Now that I am wiser(;p) active record also provides .to_sql method on the active record relation objects, to inspect the sql queries that they run against the underlying database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yep, you bet - just run this before your commands:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helps. Btw, do you know anything that would save me some key strokes and set stuff like these up automatically or by a shorter named method call?

Comment: Not sure, you could try to stick it into your /config/environments/development.rb.